# how to show history of a folder in visual studio git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I'm using visual studio 2016 git integration. If I right-click on a source file I can see the history of just that file. similarly if it's a sub-folder inside a project, I can see the history of the folder.

However, if I select a project or the solution in solution explorer, it just shows me the history of the .csproj or .sln file.

How do I see the history of the whole project or solution (i.e. the folder that corresponds to the project itself or the solution folder containing the projects)?

Answer (score 35):

You can change the *Solution Explorer* to *Folders View*

[image]

Then you can right-click to find the *View History* menu.

[image]

Answer (score 25):

Have you tried to go to the Team Explorer, and choose one of the hubs Changes, or Branches, or Sync ?  You will find a drop down menu item named Actions, and within that you will find View History.
[image]

or you can go to the different branches in the Branches Hub, right click one of the branches, and choose View History

[image]

This will show you the whole history for your repo for a given branch.
If you have multiple folders or solutions within a repo, there is currently no such feature within VS, so you then need to revert to the command line, and use git log, or the gitk for a kind of graphic view of the same, a previous answer for that is here:  [View git history for folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950037/view-git-history-for-folder)

Comment: There actually is a way to view per-project folder history. See sergiopereira's answer.

Comment: Couldn't they make it *a little* bit easier to find? :@