# Visual Studio 2015 git not show all history, just first commit

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I create some test commits and push to Visual Studio Online (VSO), however if I right click on solution and view history, it just show first commit but on VSO I can view all. I checked some old projects, this problem still happen. Any one have solution?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're right-clicking on the solution so Visual Studio is only showing you history of changes to the .SLN file.  I know, it's kind of annoying.  I use git with VSTS  (formerly Visual Studio Online) as well, but I use a combination of SourceTree and command-line for my git stuff.  I'm just not a fan of the git integration in Visual Studio.

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398090/how-to-show-history-of-a-folder-in-visual-studio-git) was posted on Stack Overflow and that [led to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950037/view-git-history-for-folder) on how to do this with the command-line.